# Thread Safety of WeakReference

Tags: c#, .net, weak-references

When using a WeakReference, how can we be sure than the target is not collected between the .IsAlive and .Target calls?

For example:

```
if (myWeakReference.IsAlive)
{
    // How can we be sure the object is still alive while here?
    ((MyType)myWeakReference.Target).Foo();
}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Just get the `Target` and check whether it's not null:

```
object target = myWeakReference.Target;
if (target != null)
{        
    ((MyType)target).Foo();
}
```

The [docs for `IsAlive`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference.isalive.aspx) specifically say:

> Because an object could potentially be
>   reclaimed for garbage collection
>   immediately after the IsAlive property
>   returns true, using this property is
>   not recommended unless you are testing
>   only for a false return value.

Answer (score 5):

The only purpose of the "IsAlive" property is for situations where you want to take some action if the target of a WeakReference has already been destroyed, but where you don't want to risk accidentally keeping it alive longer than necessary.  If one were to say, e.g.

```
  if (someWeakReference.Target == null)
    cleanup_related_object();
```

and the garbage-collector were to (for whatever reason) trigger right after the code that evaluated someWeakReference.Target, the GC would notice that there existed a strong reference to that object and preclude its collection.  On the other hand, saying:

```
  if (!someWeakReference.IsAlive)
    cleanup_related_object();
```

there would be no risk of accidentally prolonging the lifetime of the target of someWeakReference target

Answer (score 2):

You can't.  Assign myWeakReference.Target to a variable, and check for null.

Answer (score -1):

you can get rid of the if :)

(myWeakReference?.Target as MyType)?.Foo()

Comment: This does not answer OP's question but might be admissible as a comment for improvement.